# How to populate and then sort or randomize an array?

Tags: arrays, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 9.1. I am coding using CFSCRIPT.

I am creating a quiz. Query one will go get an image of a person and the person of the person in the image.  This will be the correct answer.  Query two will go get two other people who are not in the image.  I want to put this into an array and then sort the array so that the correct answer isn't always at the top or the bottom or in the middle.

Here is my pseudo SQL:

```
QUERY ONE NAME = GET CORRECT ANSWER
SELECT TOP 1 ImageID, PersonID, FirstName, LastName
FROM IMAGES

QUERY TWO NAME =  GET TWO INCORRECT ANSWERS
SELECT TOP 2 PersonID, FirstName, LastName
FROM IMAGES 
WHERE ImageID IS NOT THE CORRECT ANSWER
```

I "think" I want my array to look like this:

```
PersonID="1234";
FirstName="Bob";
LastName="Jones";
```

I need to loop through each query and populate this array with the three people returned from the query. Like this, but this code doesn't work:

```
<cfscript>
PersonArray = arrayNew(1);
for (i = 1; i lte GetTwoWrong.RecordCount; i++) {
    Person = structNew();
    Person.PersonID = GetTwoWrong.PersonID[i];
Person.FirstName = GetTwoWrong.FirstName[i];
Person.LastName = GetTwoWrong.LastName [i];
PersonArray = arrayAppend(PersonArray , Person);

}
</cfscript>
```

Then I need to sort the array by FirstName, LastName, or PersonID to create any kind of randomness.

```
<cfscript>
PersonArray = arraySort(PersonArray numeric);
</cfscript>
```

Then I will need to output the answers. The answer will be clickable. On click, I will send the PersonID via jQuery to check the answer for correctness (and store the selection).

So, how do I create an array and then populate it from two different queries and then sort it? Should I be using an array at all? A structure?

Comment: What database are you using? You could `UNION` the two queries and then (in SQL server) just sort by `NewID()`.

Comment: Dan, I need separate queries. I will be adding other criteria to gather information about each correct and incorrect answer.

Comment: Well you don't *really* need separate queries if both result sets will return the same information :). I'll post an example of what I mean as an answer.

Comment: There's also Query of Queries that you can use, to union and sort/order by whatever column you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in the database, which will be *far* less complicated. Here's an example:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 1 AS Correct, ImageID, PersonID, FirstName, LastName, UniqueToCorrectAnswer
    FROM IMAGES
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 2 0 AS Correct, ImageID, PersonID, FirstName, LastName, NULL AS UniqueToCorrectAnswer
    FROM IMAGES 
    WHERE ImageID IS NOT THE CORRECT ANSWER
) AllAnswers
ORDER BY NewID()
```

The two queries on either side of the `UNION` can be totally different against different databases, tables, and criteria, so long as they both return the same columns. You'll notice in the second query, I'm returning a NULL value for something that doesn't exist there, but does exist in the first one (just an example). So you can see how you can return different values from each side of the `UNION` and get them in a completely random order.

This is something that database servers are much better at than application code. If you need to (somewhere on the page) deal with your correct and incorrect answers differently, you can then use a Query of Query to pull just the correct or incorrect answers out of the base query.

Comment: So, your suggestion is to do it all in the query and then just dump it on the page, bypassing the need for an array at all? Actually, that's not what I asked for but is starting to make a lot of sense. Let me give it a whirl and see if I can get the query to work.....stay tuned.

Comment: Exactly, then just loop through the query as you normally would. No messy arrays, a single connection to the database, etc, etc. It solves your problem either way :)

Comment: Dan, here's the problem: I have a table of images and a table of people and a junction table. So, I want to pull from the images a person and then other people who may or may not have an image.  That's why I went and got the image first and then the person associated with that image and then two other people.

Comment: Then it's just a matter of joining things up correctly, and making the columns match in the return values, then sticking the UNION between the two. It's totally doable with the right queries. Maybe if you want to go this route, you can create a separate question to address this particular kind of solution, and we can discuss there. Would need more information on how your tables are structured to help any further.

Comment: Dan, your entire answer didn't suit my needs. You led me to the right answer though with "ORDER BY NewID()."  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you *really* want to sort and use a random array, as usual, Ben Nadel has done all the work for us:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/280-Randomly-Sort-A-ColdFusion-Array-Updated-Thanks-Mark-Mandel.htm

You then need to change your original code to use a `Duplicate` function in your `ArrayAppend` to prevent reference issues. So change this:

```
PersonArray = arrayAppend(PersonArray , Person);
```

To this:

```
arrayAppend(PersonArray , Duplicate(Person));
```

[`ArrayAppend`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_a-b_07.html) also returns a `true` or `false` value, so your assignment of the result back to the array is wiping out the information already in there. I always confuse that and `ListAppend`, which does indeed return the modified list.

```
PersonArray = arrayNew(1);

Person = structNew();
Person.PersonID = GetOneRight.PersonID;
Person.FirstName = GetOneRight.FirstName;
Person.LastName = GetOneRight.LastName;

ArrayAppend(PersonArray , Duplicate(Person));

for (i = 1; i lte GetTwoWrong.RecordCount; i++) {
    Person = structNew();
    Person.PersonID = GetTwoWrong.PersonID[i];
    Person.FirstName = GetTwoWrong.FirstName[i];
    Person.LastName = GetTwoWrong.LastName[i];
    ArrayAppend(PersonArray , Duplicate(Person));

}

//Now shuffle it using Ben's code
CreateObject("java", "java.util.Collections").Shuffle(PersonArray);
```

Comment: I agree with you on using the database for this one :) But a nice tip to keep handy for when you really do need to randomize arrays.

Comment: I am sure you could get the database to handle this particular issue, but the problem really is that I presented the question to you in such a way that it seems that this is the only problem. I will have photos with no people, one person, and multiple people. I need to be able to pull from multiple places easily. All the data in all the tables are NOT the same. There will be commonalities though.    My original question still is how do I create an array and populate it from two different queries? Any help?

Comment: This answer you just responded to has a link to sort an array randomly, and corrects two issues with you're producing that array. As for populating the array from two queries, just loop through each query individually and `ArrayAppend` as necessary. You've got all the pieces here. If things are still not working after using the suggestions above, post what's happening versus what you expect (your original post has no errors, it just says "doesn't work"). Changing your ArrayAppend and using Ben's array sort should do the trick for you.

Comment: I edited my answer to contain what I think would be the full working code block.